# Is it possible to set height value so that it is both inheritable and acts as min-height?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a single-column layout, where the body element acts as a column and has a distinctive background-color. I want the body element to fill the viewport height (currently using `100vh` for this) so that inner elements can use `height: 100%`, but if the content of body is larger than the viewport, the body should grow (so that its background-color continues with the content).

Here's some demo code:

```js
// This is just a helper code for the demo
// it's unrelated to the problem. Please, review the CSS block
let height = '';
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const newHeight = height === '' ? '2400px' : '';
  height = newHeight;
  const filler = document.querySelector('.content-filler')
  filler.style.height = newHeight;
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  background-color: white;
}

body {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #b39ddb;
  height: 100vh; /* fixed height is defined here */
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-inline: auto;
}

.column {
  height: 100%; /* this is inherited from the body's 100vh */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.bottom-row {
  margin-top: auto;
  padding: 12px;
  background: blueviolet;
}

.content-filler {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: #673ab7;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div style="padding: 8px">
    Hello world
    <div>
      <button>Toggle large content</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="content-filler">Dynamic content</div>
  </div>

  <div class="bottom-row">bottom-row</div>
</div>
```

The problem with this implementation is that when you have content of large height, the body element stays fixed at `100vh` and its background color appears to be "cut off".

Obviously this is expected for the fixed height value, but how can I solve this problem?

If I change `height: 100vh` to `min-height: 100vh`, then the child element's `height: 100%` would no longer take effect.

I tried using something like `height: minmax(100vh, fit-content)` for the `height` value, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Is there a way to solve this other then converting all elements in the tree to flex columns, starting from body?

---

UPDATE: One important use-case that I missed: further children of `.column` need to also be able to set `height: 100%`, and so on further down the tree.

Comment: How about min-height on both of them?

Comment: Right, I missed another requirement: further children of `.column` need to also be able to set `height: 100%`, and so on down the tree

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe it, I think I solved it! Though feels more like winning a lottery of accidentally finding what works.

Use these styles for `body`:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

I fiddled a lot with setting body to `flex`, but it required updating all children to flex columns as well. But to my surprise, `display: grid` behaves differently! In essence, it allows children of an element whose height is set by `min-height` to grow using `height: 100%`! And this is exactly what I was trying to achieve.

Here's the updated demo:

```js
// This is just a helper code for the demo
// it's unrelated to the problem. Please, review the CSS block
let height = '';
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const newHeight = height === '' ? '2400px' : '';
  height = newHeight;
  const filler = document.querySelector('.content-filler')
  filler.style.height = newHeight;
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  background-color: white;
}

body {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #b39ddb;
  display: grid; /* <-- this is the solution */
  min-height: 100vh; /* <-- this is the solution */
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-inline: auto;
}

.column {
  height: 100%; /* this is inherited from the body's 100vh */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.bottom-row {
  margin-top: auto;
  padding: 12px;
  background: blueviolet;
}

.content-filler {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: #673ab7;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div style="padding: 8px">
    Hello world
    <div>
      <button>Toggle large content</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="content-filler">Dynamic content</div>
  </div>

  <div class="bottom-row">bottom-row</div>
</div>
```

So far I found only one issue: when my page is inside of an iframe, it has unwanted overscroll. Fortunately in my case I can control this and set `.is-iframe` class to body, for which I change the display value back to `block`.

I will play around some more and if I don't find serious issues I'll mark this as the answer

Comment: you no more need to set height:100% on the column element when setting display:grid on body. The same can also be done with flexbox

Comment: Oh, that's correct about height: 100% for the first child. But I do need it for further children. As for flexbox, it will not work

Comment: it will work: https://jsfiddle.net/vpuezL9n/

Comment: It will not: you have updated .column to a flex-column and you need to do this to all further children. I know I missed this case in the demo, but I mentioned it in the initial question

Comment: *you have updated .column to a flex-colum* --> check your original code, you have this property since the beginning (even in your answer) ... remove it and even your answer won't work

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Here's an updated more relevat example: https://jsfiddle.net/rgo2f3hn/
Notice how the `.root` element doesn't need to be flexbox. But if you change body to flex, you need to update all children to flex-grow: 1 and display: flex column all the way down.

Comment: no you don't, you can change the body to flexbox and even remove the height: 100% from root: https://jsfiddle.net/gw6j1em0/. If display: grid works, display: flex will also work because the same stretch alignment is being used in both case. The only different is the use of flex-grow: 1 (which you may not need if you have a lot of content)

Comment: Ah, interesting, you set body to flex but not to flex column. I think under the hood this is very similar to my display: grid solution. But it's kinda quirky that in this case `height: 100%` on the .root element breaks it. So this solution explicitly affects two elements, not one.